# React inaccurately calculating the height of a div on first page load

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm looking for a solid strategy to calculate the height of a parent with many children inside, whether the children are images, videos, or fonts or  etc. (Think portfolio content)

A simple example of the issue can be found here:

### [image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/wrong-height-tkvcm?file=/src/useHeight.js:347-545

---

Images are slow to load so the calculation function gets fired prematurely. And the resulting height calculation is completely off.

Things I've tried

- Calculating the ratio of all images setting the image height explicitly. This works but then then I still have videos, fonts, slow APIs that need to be loaded too. So this strategy feels very whack-a-mole.
- ResizeObserver. Is unable to reliably wait for the content to load too. Expensive in performance. And this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67352279/resizeobserver-keeping-array-structure-when-resizing-browser-vertically-or-horiz).
- React setState/useEffect/array dependencies. Gets me pretty far but ultimately do fail because it's difficult to know which state will fire last to update the height calculation.
- I tried React concurrent mode to try to preload the content before the calculation starts. This seems overkill for non-API cases. I only have local images and assets to worry about.

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    updateHeight();
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateHeight);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateHeight);
    };
  }, [updateHeight]);
```

I do think preloading content with React is the best way to go, but I'm curious to hear if anyone else tried to solve for calculating dimensions on huge containers with lots of content inside?

More complex example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wilson-qzb1i?file=/src/components/CaseWrapper/index.js:756-836

Answer (score 4):

Size discrepancy is likely due to the custom fonts you are using. When you refresh the page you can notice the text shift after the fonts load.

Try removing all the `@font-face` in `base.css` and problem will disappear.

Alternatively, you can wait for `document.fonts.ready` callback before you compute the heights.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  document.fonts.ready.then(function () {
    console.log('Fonts currently being used on the page are now loaded.');
    // Calculate height now
  });  
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks Sohaib, definitely a useful way to manage layout thrashing, I'm gonna implement this either way. I'm hoping to find a more less whack-a-mole solution that can anticipate all sorts of assets being loaded, not just fonts. And more React-y. Perhaps there is a similar solution for images and videos. (I'm already using padding-bottom hack to prevent images from throwing the layout)

Comment: I had this exact issue and this solution no doubt saved me a load of time - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. To make sure all images are loaded, you can use the `onLoad` event on that HTML element.
2. `handleLoad` will set state 'loaded' to `true` when done.
3. Then you can pass the `'loaded'` state to `useHeight` and make sure it calculates the element, once it is done loading

```js
// App.js
...


return() (
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const height = useHeight(elementDOM, loaded); // 3.

  // 2.
  const handleLoad = () => {
    setLoaded(true);
  };
  ...
    <div ref={elementDOM} className="box" onLoad={handleLoad}> // 1.
    ..
    ..
    </div>
  ...
);
...
```

```
// useHeight.js
...
function useHeight(elementRef, isLoaded) {
  const updateHeight = useCallback(() => {
    if (isLoaded && elementRef && elementRef.current) {
      const { height } = elementRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      setHeight(height);
    }
  }, [isLoaded, elementRef]);

  ...
  return height;
  ...
}
...
```

[Forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wrong-height-forked-g5h4e?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here is a solution for anyone who runs into a similar issue. Going off the useHeight function, instead of using onLoad, which only calcuates if the main HTML has loaded and not things like images or fonts, we can add:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", updateHeight);
```

Then we don't need to use the onLoad function the target container, and we can get rid of the isLoaded property of useHeight all-together.

The final code would look like:

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useHeight = (elementRef) => {
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(null);
    
    const updateHeight = useCallback(() => { // get height of target element
        if (elementRef && elementRef.current) {
            const { height } = elementRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            setHeight(height);
        }
    }, [elementRef]);

    useEffect(() => {
        updateHeight();

        // Event listeners:
        window.addEventListener("resize", updateHeight); // adjust height on resize

        window.addEventListener("load", updateHeight); // ensure page fully loads content before checking height

        // Remove Event Listeners:
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", updateHeight);
            window.removeEventListener("load", updateHeight); 
        };
    }, [updateHeight]);
    
    return height;
}

export default useHeight;
```